# Scala Collections Optional Tuple flatMap

Tags: collections, tuples, option-type

Just practicing/playing with scala collections and using partials. Though I can't seem to figure out how to type match for flatMap when map will map correctly to a list. I'm aware there are other ways(skip to ending) just curious how this would work.

```
val fours = Map( 1 -> 4, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 12)
def greaterTuple( k:Int, v:Int):Option[(Int, Int)] = if(v > 4) Some(k,v) else None

fours.flatMap { case (k,v) => greaterTuple(k,v) }  //works
fours.flatMap( x => greaterTuple(x._1, x._2))      //works
fours.map( (greaterTuple _).tupled)                //works

fours.flatMap( (greaterTuple _).tupled)    

 Error:(27, 56) type mismatch;
 found   : ((Int, Int)) => Option[(Int, Int)]
 required: ((Int, Int)) => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

So other than changing the function signature to something like

```
def greaterTuple( t: (Int,Int)):Option[(Int,Int)] = if(t._2 > 4) Some(t) else None
```

Making everything as easy

```
fours.flatMap(greaterTuple)
fours.map(greaterTuple)
```

or before someone suggests: inline the whole thing just not my point

```
fours.filter(t => t._2 > 4)
```

So how do you type cast it as optional?

Maybe you don't worry and just except the aforementioned

```
fours.flatMap { case (k,v) => greaterTuple(k,v) }
```

** Aside why is there so much complaint on t._1/2/etc.. if you are ever at most working with a single tuple to pass to a function. I feel like it's a part of the language we should use it were it makes sense and idiomatic otherwise; end rant.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So how do you type cast it as optional?

Comment: I posted an edit on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala `Option` is not a traversable, so `flatMap` doesn't work. You can't cast an `Option` into a traversable. The `map` operation returns an `Iterable[Option[(Int, Int)]]`. 2.12 has an operation `flatten` that you can use on the result of the `map`. It'll filter out the empty `Option`s and convert the non-empty ones into `(Int, Int)`.

I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve using the `flatMap`. Do you want an `Iterable[(Int, Int)]`?

**Edit**:

I overlooked `implicit Option.option2Iterable: Option[A] => Iterable[A]`, and @JustDave's syntax was wrong.

```
scala> fours.flatMap((greaterTuple _).tupled(_))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 8, 3 -> 12)
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002864/monads-left-unit-law-does-not-seem-to-hold-for-lists-in-scala-are-scala-lists/45003045).

Comment: Yup, just wanted to know if it was possible and if not why which you answered.