# Monad's left unit law does not seem to hold for Lists in scala. Are scala Lists not monads then?

Tags: scala, monads

Monads' "left unit law":

```
unit(x) flatMap f == f(x)
```

But:

```
(List(1) flatMap ((x: Int) => Some[Int](x))) == List(1) // true
((x: Int) => Some[Int](x))(1) == Some(1) // also true
```

So left unit law does not hold for lists in scala. Are lists not monads then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the monad law assumes `f: A => M[A]` (here `f: A => List[A]`). This is not true of `(x: Int) => Some[Int](x)`.

Second, `List`'s `flatMap` is *not* monadic bind. It is more general than bind, because it takes an implicit `CanBuildFrom` that allows it to change its return type depending on what you want it to return. You can restrict it to bind like so

```
def bind[A](xs: List[A])(f: A => List[A]) = xs.flatMap(f) // implicit (List.canBuildFrom)
```

Now you can see that the law is satisfied:

```
bind(List(1))(x => List(x, x)) == List(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a category theory or Haskell expert but I don't understand your question, and my response is too big for comment, not to mention code blocks look terrible in comment.

Haskell left identity law is `return a >>= f ≡ f a`, right?

In Scala:

```
return -> apply
>>=    -> flatMap
```

So, left identity law for Scala `List` would be `List(a).flatMap(f) = f(a)`

In your case, `val a = 1` and `val f = (x: Int) => Some[Int](x)`. But this wouldn't even compile because `Option` is not a `GenTraversableOnce`; you can't return `Option` from a `List.flatMap`.

Instead, if we define `val f = (x: Int) => List(x * 2)`, a double function

```
LHS: List(a).flatMap(f) = List(2)
RHS: f(a) = List(2)
```

LHS = RHS, left identity satisfied.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You've overlooked `implicit Option.option2Iterable: Option[A] => Iterable[A]`.

Comment: @HTNW How do I bring that in scope?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. The implicit resolution rules will automatically be used to turn `Some[Int](x)` into `option2Iterable(Some[Int](x))`.

Comment: @HTNW Interestingly, it doesn't *always* work. `List(1).flatMap(Some(_))` = `List(1)`, no problem, but `val f = (x: Int) => Some(x)`; `List(1).flatMap(f)` gives `error: type mismatch` using 2.12.2.

Comment: NVM, I needed `List(1).flatMap(f(_))`. Thanks.